# Bootstrap 4 row at the end of container with 100% height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So I've tried everything I could thing of but I still cannot get what I want.

I have this container with `min-height: 100px;` and `height: 100%`. In that container I have two rows. See picture below. **I want row 2 to be at the end of the container**

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container-fluid full-height">
    <div class="row"> <!-- ROW 1  -->
        <div class="col-12 item-title bg-info">
            <h2> Fortress </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 item-description bg-danger">
            Niš Fortress is a fortress in the city of Niš, Serbia. It is a complex and important cultural and
            historical monument. It rises on the right bank of the Nišava River, overlooking the area inhabited
            for longer than two millennia.

            It was protected by law in May 1948 as it was declared a cultural site of great significance. The
            current condition of the fortress lists it as one of the best preserved fortifications of this kind
            in Serbia as well as on the Balkan Peninsula.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"> <!-- ROW 2  -->
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-8 col-sm-12 bg-info">
            <div class="container-fluid no-lf-padding">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        Work hours:
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        Monday 12:00 - 16:00
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        Tuesday 12:00 - 16:00
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        Wednesday 12:00 - 16:00
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        Thursday 12:00 - 16:00
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        Friday 12:00 - 16:00
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        Saturday 12:00 - 16:00
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        Sunday 12:00 - 16:00
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-4 col-sm-12 bg-warning">
            <div class="container-fluid no-lf-padding">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        Adress
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        Phone
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        Website
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.no-lf-margin {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.no-lf-padding {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
/*HERE IS FOR THE CONTAINER*/
     .full-height {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

---

I've tried :

- adding `align-items-end` to the row 2, there is no change.
- creating a `<div class="container align-self-end"> ROW AND CODE HERE </div>`, tried putting align-self-end, no change.

What am I missing ?

**Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a1e0htsw/**

Comment: Can you explain a bit more by what you mean _"I want row 2 to be at the end of the container"_? Do you want it to be at the bottom of the page like a footer?

Comment: are you trying to do something alike https://jsfiddle.net/bj2xehs9/ ? your are from the begining missing `html,body {height:100%;}`

Comment: @G-Cyr yes this is great ! But the orange part - address is a a bit down. not in the same height as the work hours.

Comment: remove your `align-items-end` class, because this is what it does. :) https://jsfiddle.net/kzf79sqj/ you should learn flex to understand the use of the bootstrap class :( https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/   and probably read with more attention the bootstrap documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/

Comment: @G-Cyr Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `flex-fill` class and flexbox (`d-flex flex-column`) on the container...

```
    <div class="container-fluid full-height d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="row">
            ..
        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-end flex-fill">
            <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-8 col-sm-12 bg-info">
                ..
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-4 col-sm-12 bg-warning">
                ..
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/p/LIQzZfOsDF

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this with flex if I understand you correctly, something like this.

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="row-one">
  </div>
  <div class="row-two">
  </div>
</div>
```

And add css

```
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `body` should take all available space of the viewport (100vh). Since you are using Bootstrap you can add these classes to the `container`

```
h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between
```

whithout Bootstrap should be:

```
.container-fluid.full-height {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Adding `align-items-end` to the second row it's not working because it refers to children elements, not self element.

Code:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.no-lf-margin {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.no-lf-padding {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
        <div class="container-fluid h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 item-title bg-info">
                    <h2> Fortress </h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 item-description bg-danger">
                    Niš Fortress is a fortress in the city of Niš, Serbia. It is a complex and important cultural and
                    historical monument. It rises on the right bank of the Nišava River, overlooking the area inhabited
                    for longer than two millennia.

                    It was protected by law in May 1948 as it was declared a cultural site of great significance. The
                    current condition of the fortress lists it as one of the best preserved fortifications of this kind
                    in Serbia as well as on the Balkan Peninsula.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-8 col-sm-12 bg-info">
                    <div class="container-fluid no-lf-padding">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                Work hours:
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                Monday 12:00 - 16:00
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                Tuesday 12:00 - 16:00
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                Wednesday 12:00 - 16:00
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                Thursday 12:00 - 16:00
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                Friday 12:00 - 16:00
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                Saturday 12:00 - 16:00
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                Sunday 12:00 - 16:00
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-4 col-sm-12 bg-warning">
                    <div class="container-fluid no-lf-padding">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                Adress
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                Phone
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                Website
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first add display:flex to container and then add flex-grow: 1; to first row.

```css
.body-wrapper
        {
            min-height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .row
        {
            padding: 2rem;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .section1{
            background-color: #f00;
            flex-grow: 1;
        }

        .section2{
            background-color: #00f;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <div class="container-fluid body-wrapper">
        <div class="row section1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur delectus ipsa perferendis provident quae quam! Aliquam blanditiis corporis itaque laudantium nihil obcaecati ratione temporibus! Est pariatur perferendis rerum soluta veniam?
        </div>

        <div class="row section2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum delectus distinctio eum libero minima odit, possimus rem! Autem consequuntur fugiat id magnam necessitatibus nihil obcaecati tempore unde? Reprehenderit, ut, velit.
        </div>
    </div>
```